# SpringSecurity nao funciona

Tags: java, spring-boot, login, spring-security

Vi tantos videos e exemplos, mas todos parecem nao funcionar/estar desatualizado, principalmente aqueles que usa o extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Quero apenar criar uma tela de login e com o spring security fazer a requisicao no banco de dados para verificar se o usuario existe e permitir ele de entrar na aplicação mas com o spring security nao estou conseguindo fazer isto.